# Quick way of finding complementary vectors in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, combinations

I have a matrix of `N` rows of binary vectors, i.e.

```
mymatrix = [ 1 0 0 1 0;
             1 1 0 0 1;
             0 1 1 0 1;
             0 1 0 0 1;
             0 0 1 0 0;
             0 0 1 1 0;
             ....       ]
```

where I'd like to find the combinations of rows that, when added together, gets me exactly:

```
[1 1 1 1 1]
```

So in the above example, the combinations that would work are `1/3`, `1/4/5`, and `2/6`.

The code I have for this right now is:

```
i = 1;
for j = 1:5
    C = combnk([1:N],j); % Get every possible combination of rows
    for c = 1:size(C,1)
        if isequal(ones(1,5),sum(mymatrix(C(c,:),:)))
            combis{i} = C(c,:);
            i = i+1;
        end
    end
end
```

But as you would imagine, this takes a while, especially because of that `combnk` in there.

What might be a useful algorithm/function that can help me speed this up?

Comment: This is the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), which is NP-complete, meaning for large numbers of vectors it gets very computationally expensive. Especially if you're interested in finding *all* the solutions. How large are your vectors likely to get? With only 5-element vectors, you'll have a max of 32 rows, which should be manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
M = [
 1 0 0 1 0;
 1 1 0 0 1;
 0 1 1 0 1;
 0 1 0 0 1;
 0 0 1 0 0;
 0 0 1 1 0;
 1 1 1 1 1
];

% Find all the unique combinations of rows...
S = (dec2bin(1:2^size(M,1)-1) == '1');

% Find the matching combinations...
matches = cell(0,1);

for i = 1:size(S,1)
    S_curr = S(i,:);
    
    rows = M(S_curr,:);
    rows_sum = sum(rows,1);
    
    if (all(rows_sum == 1))
        matches = [matches; {find(S_curr)}];
    end
end
```

To display your matches in a good stylized way:

```
for i = 1:numel(matches)
    match = matches{i};
    
    if (numel(match) == 1)
        disp(['Match found for row: ' mat2str(match) '.']);
    else
        disp(['Match found for rows: ' mat2str(match) '.']);
    end
end
```

This will produce:

> Match found for row: 7.
>
> Match found for rows: [2 6].
>
> Match found for rows: [1 4 5].
>
> Match found for rows: [1 3].

In terms of efficiency, in my machine this algoritm is completing the detection of matches in about `2 milliseconds`.